# Can I parallelize huge integer additions?

Tags: multicore

I will need to add two unsigned 256 megabit integers over two billion times.  Since carrying is obviously very important in addition and cannot be determined without waiting for lower order bits to be added, are there any performance gains to be had from multicore CPU features, such as splitting the number into multiple parts and dealing with carries later?

Comment: You may want to look into hardware ALU design. Something like a software implementation of a Carry-lookahead adder could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely separate this up into many pieces. For example, take these two numbers:

```
  12345
+ 67890
```

Now we'll split them after the third digit, between the hundreds and tens columns. This gives us

```
  123      45
+ 678    + 90
```

Calculate the results of each

```
  123      45
+ 678    + 90
-------------
  801     135
```

On the left number set you need to know how many digits you chopped off, in this case, two digits, so add two zeros back onto the end of 801, giving you 80100. And add 135 to it, and you have 80235.

You could do this with much larger numbers, and as many splits as you would like. Using this method prevents any carrying from occurring.

Of course, when you recombine large numbers you're still left with large additions. You could probably figure out how many digits have carried, and just add that small amount to your left-hand number.

For instance, in our above example, our number on the right ended up going from 2 columns to 3 columns, with the result being 135. So the extra column is the number to be carried, which could be added to your 801. This allows you to add to the small number, and then just concatenate the two numbers like you would a string

45 and 90 both took up two columns, which added made 135. We take any extra columns generated, in this case, just the 1, and add it to our left-hand number, 801.

```
801 + 1 = 802   
802 concatenated with 35 = 80235
```

If you want something extremely efficient, I'm sure you could look-up how 32-bit processors add 64-bit or larger numbers. I'm sure they do something similar for 64-bit numbers, adding the two 32-bit sections, and carrying over from the least significant 32-bit to the most significant.

And in terms of parallelization, split up your number into 32-bit pairs to be added together, then determine how many available threads the CPU can handle at once, and split up your list of pairs by that much and give that much to each thread. When the results are calculated, put them in a completed section.

The trick of carrying the numbers from the least significant to the most significant once you get all the results back will be tricky, as adding even a single 1 value to a number can cause it roll over another number as well.

Comment: Are you sure that this is especially efficient? Considering that additions are simple (

Comment: Sorry, I was interrupted mid-comment. Are you sure that this is especially efficient? Considering that additions are simple (few clock cycles) you will most likely saturate the memory bus as it is. Adding more threads will probably make the app slower as memory accesses from the different cores will collide when competing for the memory bus. My suggestion is to use a standard library or to optimize according to cache line sizes.

Comment: I agree. My answer was mostly to get the OP thinking about ways you could split up integer additions to run in parallel. Making it efficient would take some more work. If there is already a library for this (and there likely is), he/she should probably just use that instead rather than reinvent the wheel. However if this is a learning exercise then he might want to do it him/herself.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [GMP library](http://gmplib.org/)?

Comment: Because I'm not convinced that it will perform to the theoretical maximum.  Maybe it would.

Comment: Are you expecting that by posing a question here on SO you expect there will be a high likelihood of someone suggesting a better implementation than GMP's? You can always check out the GMP documentation to see the overall knowledge and reasoning levels that are the foundation of the software. Then you can compare it with what people write here.

Comment: Yes, actually, that is exactly why I asked the SO community.  Is that a problem?

Comment: It's never a problem. I'm not quite sure what the "yes" is about: is it because you expect a high-quality answer here or because you have read but are unconvinced by the GMP documentation? I guess part of the learning experience is about finding out where to turn for help. Considering that similar questions have been asked numerous times here those who have posted high-quality answers a few times will not be inclined to do so over and over again because they feel their time is too valuable. My advice in that respect is to browse older posts rather than asking the same question again.

Comment: Here's what I don't get about that.  People say that occasionally, but I do browse older posts and don't see anything that answers my question.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you mouseover the tags you will find information about the number members interested in that subject:

- multicore - 118
- multi-threading - 2.1k
- C - 11.7k
- C++ - 17k
- performance 1.3k
- spinlock - 5
- atomic - 18

You can choose one subject and then narrow down the number of questions by adding another/others.

Your original post had to do with more efficient addition using multicore so multicore would be one tag to select. Since multi-threading is part of any os or app using multicore select that. You now have 117 questions. You might want to select questions by users with more points rather than fewer. Look at the tags for individual questions and avoid those with C#, Java and .Net since those subjects are more about code production efficiency rather than code execution efficiency.

Other concepts you can search for are affinity, critical section, saturation, memory lock/barrier, thread-safe, rdtsc.

One thing you might keep in mind is that the practicalities of writing really fast code have very much to do with trial and error, getting your feet wet or whatever you might want to call it. What you can find here are hints about what you can try, what you would want to look out for.

As to my original answer with GMP, I recommend you check out the [author's page](http://gmplib.org/~tege). It contains information on things such as sustained instruction throughput on different x86 architectures, division by constant integer using integer multiplication and winning the Simon Singh Code Book challenge. There is also performance inforamtion about GMP itself.